# Angular httpclient not getting correct status in catchError

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, ionic5

I have an application with Spring Boot(2.1.1.RELEASE) backend and Ionic/Angular 13 front-end. The way it's setup is after login we send a JWT to the ui and there's an interceptor that adds the token to all requests, this is all pretty standard

The expectation in the interceptor is that when the token is expired it will get a 401 and then we send a refresh request it will get a new JWT token and then continue doing whatever it was supposed to do

Everything is working fine except for the part were I would expect a 401 code in the exception, for some reason that always comes back as zero

Here's the ui code:

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<Object>> {
    let authReq = req;
    const token = this.tokenService.getToken();
    if (token != null) {
      authReq = this.addTokenHeader(req, token);
    }
    return next.handle(authReq).pipe(catchError(error => {
      console.log(error);
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && !authReq.url.includes('auth/login') && error.status === 401) { //always false since error.status is always zero
        return this.handle401Error(authReq, next);
      } else{
        console.log(error, authReq, error.status);
      }
      return throwError(error);
    }));
  }
```

I've seen in some places that this has something to do with CORS but if that's the case why is everything else working fine? Even the refresh token works, meaning if I comment out the part that checks for 401 and send refresh for every error that works fine

Here's the backend code, cleaned for brevity

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

// Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AlwaysSendUnauthorized401AuthenticationEntryPoint());
    }
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:8100"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET","POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can inspect response in browser Network tab

Comment: You disabled CORS: `cors().disable()`, so you can't see the response in your client.